# How to determine which enemy is hit and destroy it alone

Tags: javascript, jquery

http://jsfiddle.net/5DB6K/

I have this game being made where you shoot enemies from the sides of the screen. I've got the bullets moving and being removed when they reach the end of the screen (if they didn't hit any enemy) and removing the enemy when they collide with it.

```
//------------collision----------------//
        if(shot === true){

            bulletY = $('.bullet').position().top + 2;
            bulletX = $('.bullet').position().left + 2;

            $('.enemy').each(function(){

                if($('.enemy').hasClass('smallEnemy')){
                enemyY = $(this).position().top + 7;
                enemyX = $(this).position().left + 7;

                if(Math.abs(bulletY - enemyY) <= 9 && Math.abs(bulletX - enemyX) <=9){

                    $(this).remove();
                    score = score + 40;
                    bulletDestroy();

                }
              }

           });
        }
```

However, the bullet destroys every enemy if the collision check is right which isn't what I want. I want to check if the enemy has the class of either smallEnemy, medEnemy, or lrgEnemy and then do the collision check which is what I thought I had but it doesn't seem to work.

Also, the game starts to lag the more and more time goes on. Would anyone know the reason for that?

Comment: I can only guess at the lagging - you likely need to null some vars

Answer (score 0):

This will remove all enemies any time a small enemy is present, due to your `.each` conditions.  Try this:

```
if($(this).hasClass('smallEnemy')){
            enemyY = $(this).position().top + 7;
            enemyX = $(this).position().left + 7;

            if(Math.abs(bulletY - enemyY) <= 9 && Math.abs(bulletX - enemyX) <=9){

                $(this).remove();
                score = score + 40;
                bulletDestroy();

            }
```

As for lag, it's due to memory availability and overhead.  Instead of looping through your "enemeies", I would attach an observer to your bullets, and whenever they intersect with `.enemy` you should fire a custom event to remove `this` enemey.  Much less code too.

Comment: when you say fire your custom event, are you talking about just another function that would take care of removing the enemy, removing the bullet, and increasing the score?

Comment: No, just an event (only custom named), like "click" or "mouse in".  You could bind functions to that event to do things like removing the bullet and increasing the score from there.  This will work better in the long run. Say you decide to add "allies" or a new breed of enemy, then all you need to do is bind new handlers instead of looping through all of your new elements in addition to the old.